# What carries over to New Game Plus?

Tags: atelier-meruru-apprentice-of-arland

What carries over to New Game+ when loading from Clear Data after a finished game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All equipped gear, **including development equipment**. If you have some time left at the end of the game, focus on synthesizing the best development equipment so you'll have it out of the gate for your next run.

Unlike *Atelier Totori*, your money is not carried over.

Because the Warp Gate is not development equipment, it is not carried over.